# Change events for swing data object

Tags: java, swing, event-handling

How do I implement an change event / event listener for just a data change.
I have a color chooser pop up which you can select a new color for part of the swing GUI.
I get the selected color and set a value.

In another part of the code I need to know when the color value changes so I can then redraw the GUI with the new color.

I know how to add a changeListener to a swing object but how do I generate the change event and implement that part.

Comment: 21 questions asked. 0 answers accepted. I think I'll skip this one.

Answer (score 2):

Use property change listeners/supports for bounded properties (For more information, please see [Bound Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html#bound))